# Matching two sets of numbers for equality

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Chat Room: `id (INT)`  `creator_user_id (INT)`

Chat Participants: `participant_user_id (INT)` `chat_room_id (INT - FR)`

I want to:

**Find a Chat Room, where `User 1` is the creator and `User 2 & 3` are the ONLY participants.**

What have I got so far:

```
SELECT rcc.*,

COUNT(*) as participant_count,

GROUP_CONCAT(rcp.user_id) as participants

FROM
   `chat_rooms` cr

LEFT JOIN chat_participants cp on cp.chat_room_id = cr.id

WHERE rcc.user_id = 1

GROUP BY rcc.id

HAVING participant_count = 2 AND participants = '2,3'  <--- this doesn't look nice
```

Problem:

I have two sets of numbers that I want to match for equality. Set `2,3` is my input and I want to match it against `GROUP_CONCAT(rcp.user_id) as participants` for equality regardless of their order in their respective sets.

What I'm doing above is a string comparison which obviously isn't the right way to go.

Thanks all.

Comment: could you please let me know how do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write this as:

```sql
SELECT cr.id
FROM chat_rooms cr
INNER JOIN chat_participants cp
    ON cp.chat_room_id = cr.id
WHERE cr.creator_user_id = 1
GROUP BY cr.id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT participant_user_id) = 2 AND
    SUM(participant_user_id NOT IN (2, 3)) = 0;
```